# How to shut down the music in background mode on IOS program?

Tags: ios, background-music

I make a iOS program to use the `AVAudioPlayer` to play music on the background. But I don't know how to shut down the music after a certain time.
I try to use the `UILocalNotification` to stop music in the method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

But the way only effectly after the user recieved the Notification and click to shut down!

How can I stop the music automatically after a certain time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use AVPlayer instead of AVAudioPlayer you can achieve this using  `addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:queue:usingBlock:`

I have tried this with AVQueuePlayer (which is a subclass of AVPlayer) and it worked.

Try something like this:

```
id observer = [avPlayer addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:CMTimeMake(60, 1)]] queue:NULL usingBlock:^{
        [avPlayer pause];
    }];
```

And somewhere later:

```
[avPlayer removeTimeObserver:observer];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I slove it by the way! But Can the AVQueuePlayer play with a loop way?

Comment: I suggest registering for `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` and then either restart the song, or enqueuing it again. But I haven't done this in background, so I'm not sure. Please tell me if you succeed or if you run in to more problems. Good luck!

Comment: Nice answer. Much better than mine! I'd upvote you twice if I could.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to be proved wrong, but I believe that what you're asking to do might be impossible. My impression is that if the user actually clicks the Home button to send your app into the background, it can't function as a "sleep timer", because you can't run a timer. Apple's own apps can do this sort of thing, but they have special privileges.

For example, look at this app:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/music-sleep-timer/id320583424?mt=8

Look at how he says, "Remember to keep this app in the foreground!" Clearly that's because once the app is background, the timer stops working.

You might be better off advising the user to resort to the countdown timer in Apple's Clock app. It can shut down your music and put the device to sleep.

Comment: Thanks for your help!But in acturally there are many app already achieve the function!such as https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/super-hypnotist/id378451417?l=en&mt=8 or https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/qq-yin-le/id414603431?l=en&mt=8  so I think there must be a way to eachieve

Comment: Well, there are ways to achieve the same effect by trickery. Let's say you have a 30-minute music file. And you only want to play 10 minutes of it. Then you can use the iOS's editing ability to create a new music file consisting of just the first ten minutes of that file. So it plays, the user puts you in the background, and if the file comes to an end, the music stops (and your app is suspended, since it is no longer playing).

Comment: that‘s a way! But if the file is only 10 minutes and I want repeat to play it after 30 minutes,that what I confuse!

Comment: Again, you could make a queue consisting of this file three times.

Comment: Thanks! your way can slove my problem but I think use the AVAudioPlayer and run the [avPlayer addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:CMTimeMake(60, 1)]] queue:NULL usingBlock:^{
        [avPlayer pause];}]; method is more better!